# Generator for Time Series Analysis using RNN

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, recurrent-neural-network

I have a problem with a generator function for time series analysis using Recurrent Neural Network. I have a dataset with 5 different CDS quotes. And I want to analyze these with Recurrent Neural Network in a Multiinput/Multioutput network. 5 quotes as input and 5 quotes as output.

Therefore I have a generator which converts several inputs in one output and I´m not able to change this code for my purpose.

Lookback is how far the network should go back,
delay is the time horizon to be forecasted and
step is 1 because I have daily data and no deeper insides of hourly or minutes data.
With the index one can decide which rows should inside the subset (train, validation, test).

Here is the code:

```
generator <- function(data, lookback, delay, min_index, max_index,
                  shuffle = FALSE, batch_size = 128, step = 1) {
if (is.null(max_index))
    max_index <- nrow(data) - delay - 1
i <- min_index + lookback
 function() {
    if (shuffle) {
        rows <- sample(c((min_index+lookback):max_index), size = batch_size)
    } else {
        if (i + batch_size >= max_index)
            i <<- min_index + lookback
        rows <- c(i:min(i+batch_size-1, max_index))
        i <<- i + length(rows)
    }
    
    samples <- array(0, dim = c(length(rows), 
                                lookback / step,
                                dim(data)[[-1]]))
    targets <- array(0, dim = c(length(rows)))

    for (j in 1:length(rows)) {
        indices <- seq(rows[[j]] - lookback, rows[[j]]-1, 
                       length.out = dim(samples)[[2]])
        samples[j,,] <- data[indices,]
        targets[[j]] <- data[rows[[j]] + delay, 1]
    }            
    
    list(samples, targets)
}
```

}

Hope someone can help me with this problem or has some other helpful links for building up a RNN with time series financial data.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

O.K,
it seems that I found out the solution on my own. 
Instead of

```
targets <- array(0, dim = c(length(rows)))
```

which is a vector, I used

```
targets <- array(0, dim = c(length(rows),dim(data)[[-1]]))
```

which is now a matrix.

And then just write

```
targets[j,] <- data[rows[[j]] + delay, ]
```

instead of

```
targets[[j]] <- data[rows[[j]] + delay, 1]
```

This generator creates a 3D Tensor for multiple outputs.